# How to get property gettee function

Tags: python, properties

I need to take fget, fset and fdel attributes from the property. Do you have any ideas on how to do this?

I've tried to look at related topics on stackoverflow and looked for the property api to do that, but haven't found any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call getattr() on class. Calling on instance will not works

```
import dis

class LinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, value, next_node=None):
        self._next = next_node
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return f'<{self.value}, {str(self.next)}>'

    @property
    def next(self):
        return self._next

    @next.setter
    def next(self, node):
        if type(node) is LinkedListNode or node is None:
            self._next = node
        raise ValueError()

    @next.deleter
    def next(self):
        print(f'Delete _next attribute of node {self.value}')
        del(self._next)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = LinkedListNode(10)
    y = LinkedListNode(9, x)
    print(y)
    z = getattr(LinkedListNode, 'next')
    print('---------FGET-----------')
    dis.dis(z.fget)
    print('---------FSET-----------')
    dis.dis(z.fset)
    print('---------FDEL-----------')
    dis.dis(z.fdel)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions on this question. The one is using vars(cls) or ClassName.**dict** to get the link to propetry object through the mapping_proxy object(similar to dictionary).